# dygraph renders 9 times slower with 3 series compared to single series

Tags: performance, dygraphs

When I render a single time series using Dygraph for a measurement with 9000 samples, it took only 0.2 second.  However, when I render 3 time series (the same as the single series with 9000 samples but with 2 additional measurements) on the same graph it took almost 10 second-- a 50 times difference.

Is that expected?  Any suggestion on how I can optimize?

Please advise.

Comment: Please share a link to your performance tests -- it's hard to help you investigate without knowing the specifics.

Comment: I would emphasize Dan's point to take the time to post your code and performance tests, since I do something similar with thousands of data points and performance is very quick. This is actually my primary reason for choosing this great library.